# How can I return files part of the lambda environment in html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to return the full html from lambda to the browser, and I've gotten that part fine.

However I want to include some js scripts in the html like `<script src="tools.js"></script>` and then run some of those functions in the html.
The file tools.js is stored in lambda.

But when I run it in the browser, I get an error that tools.js couldn't be loaded.

Any ideas on what might be causing this behaviour?

This is a node js 12 environment, I'm calling it through API gateway via lambda proxy integration and a custom domain name.

The rest of the html returns just fine.

Thank you very much in advance. I've googled a lot trying to find the answer without any luck.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.
This can be done using a cloudfront distribution.